# doppler shift through two mediums

Tags: electromagnetism, doppler-effect

When considering the Doppler shift, the 'canonical equation' is 
$$f=\frac{c+vr}{c+vs}f_0$$

However, this equation seems to run into trouble in the following situation: A light source inside water is moving at a speed $v$ towards a receiver outside the water. Can we modify the above equation to deal with a transition between two media? Or is there a completely different formula that applies here?

Comment: Why did you re-post this question?

Comment: Please do not re-post questions.

Comment: Damnit, I spent time reformulating it to make it look more legit. @dmckee shall I apply that edit to the previously posted question?

Comment: @Danu If you feel up to it. I don't think there is anything wrong with the questions as far as belonging on Physics SE.

Comment: @dmckee My edit just makes the formulation cleaner & clearer. I'm trying to be active in steering potentially mediocre (or worse) questions in the right direction, as I feel more of us should try to do :)

Comment: I agree in principle, but life as a junior professor is not leaving me a lot of time, so I'm just handling the basic moderation tasks and leaving that kind of thing up to our Good Samaritans. @Danu

Comment: @dmckee I wasn't aiming that comment at you ;) Good luck teaching (and god knows what other tasks you have to do :P)

Comment: sorry for duplication